# Am I able to add more fields to a vuetify calendar event?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

I would like to add more fields than just the name, and the start and end time to an event on the v-calendar. Is there a way I can add something like Description: "this is the description of the event" under the name and time? on day view?

Comment: Please share your code and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know this is not possible.
Not inside vuetify. What is done in some cases is the separation of information using - or, or line breaks. But there is a problem because the long text is not visible.
What can be done today?
Use a dialog to show the details of the event. you can show the details of the event by hovering over the reminder.
See how to do this in the vuetify documentation itself.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/#click